# Когда я на Небо/небо пойду

Tags: заглавная

Это существительное надо здесь по-маленькому или по-большому писать?

`А когда же я сама на Небо/небо пойду – я не знаю.`

Comment: "И вы ему порядком отплатили:
Как из стремян вы вышибли его,
Он сутки замертво лежал — и вряд ли
Оправился". Александр Пушкин.
Скупой рыцарь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*А когда же я сама на **Небо** пойду – я не знаю.*

В данном случае условное значение (имя собственное): Небо как Царство Небесное.

Е. Лукин. Портрет кудесника в юности. 2004
https://author.today/work/140176

*– А когда, даст Бог, попадешь в **Царство Небесное,** сам убедишься: нипочем твой Ахиллес черепаху не догонит.*

*– А если не даст?*

*– А если не даст, то плохо...*

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149091/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Answer (score 0):

Никак не правильно, ввиду того, что не ясно вообще о чём речь. Если имеется ввиду *небо* -

- в обычном смысле, воздушная среда, то не ясно, что значит "пойду на небо", это примерно как сказать "поплаваю в асфальте". Возможно, где-то уместно, но в примере явно не достаточно информации, чтобы сделать выводы о смысле сказанного.
- в религиозном смысле, неоправданно употребление "пойду", потому что так не говорят, но в крайнем случае *небо* стоит писать с большой буквы, потому что написание Бог, Небеса и тд. закреплено канонами употребления слов. Хотя в 19 веке писали всё с маленькой буквы почти всегда, сейчас пишут с маленькой буквы, особенно **когда речь идет о личном восприятии** религиозных моментов, а не только, если о боге пишут атеисты.

*..Вымети сор с **неба**,

Смотри, уже нет места

Звёздочке моей маленькой,

Крохотной моей звёздочке,

Что не оставит меня.

Иду топтать тропу в **небо**,

Втыкать вешки, чужим не осмыслить.

Придут суки пытать, где мы,

А мы дома

давным-давно…* Веня Д'ркин.

*Иду топтать тропу в небо* - стоить заметить, что тут уместно "иду".

В общем, не стоит писать с большой буквы, когда не знаете, не уверены, о чём пишите.